# handling keyboard scan codes directly in VB KeyPress event

Tags: vb.net

How to map Numpad scan codes to keys  in VB KeyPress event?

Meaning I want to track key 1 when NUMLOCK is ON   OR OFF.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use GetKeyState API function.