# Visual Studio 2012, virtual keypress combination

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am a newbie in Visual studio,
I don't know how to press keyboard keys virtually.

```
    If (text1.Text = 1) Then
        'code for CTRL+DOWN
    End If
    If (text1.Text = 2) Then
        'code for CTRL+UP
    End If
```

I have no idea how to press keys virtually,
Please help

Comment: What UI framework? Also, what are you trying to accomplish? That's generally the wrong approach.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/964088/10396) and [this MS knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320583) linked from the answers.

Comment: Don't "press keys".  Do whatever those keys are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/). You can make combinations with this library.

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C)
```